# Detecting long press events on Chips in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a list of chips in Jetpack Compose, and I was wondering how it would be possible to detect long press events on them?

Code:

```
SuggestionChip(
    onClick = {
        onQuickPresetTapped()
    },
    label = {
        Text(text = "${quickPreset.width}x${quickPreset.height}")
    }
)
```

Currently I have only successfully detected simple click events, although I want the app to be able to detect long click event as well.

I have tried many Stack Overflow solutions, such as the following:

```
SuggestionChip(
    label = {
        Text(text = "${quickPreset.width}x${quickPreset.height}")
    },
    onClick = { },
    modifier = Modifier.combinedClickable(
        onClick = { onQuickPresetTapped() },
        onLongClick = { onQuickPresetLongPressed() }
    )
)
```

... which did not fix the problem.

Another thing I tried is wrapping the chip in a box with a long click and click event like so:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.combinedClickable(
        onClick = { onQuickPresetTapped() },
        onLongClick = { onQuickPresetLongPressed() }
    )
) {
    SuggestionChip(
        onClick = {
            onQuickPresetTapped()
        },
        label = {
            Text(text = "${quickPreset.width}x${quickPreset.height}")
        }
    )
}
```

... this also did not solve the problem.

How can I get long press events to work on chips? I have tried many things without success.

Comment: The `Chip` doesn't support the `onLongClick`. It is based on a clickable `Surface` which implements an internal `clickable` modifier.

Comment: I haven't used m3 yet, and Gabriele provided better answer, I deleted mine, apologies

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thanks for your reply. so where do I go now? I really need long press support to delete items in a list of chips, is there a way around it that you're aware of? I am quite shocked that this isn't simple functionality, it makes it seem like Compose is still in early phases. :( Would creating a custom view that looks like a chip work?

Comment: @tomtomkt You can build a custom Chip, or use something different, as a `FilterChip` using  the `selected` attribute to mark all the chips to delete: the user selects the chips and delete all of them.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a perfect way to do this as far as I know, aside from rolling your own widget.

Here is a "poor man's" version that basically works by capturing the long press on the attached text label.  It's not perfect since it doesn't handle long presses on the part of the chip that is not covered by text.  This affects accessibility.
Also, because it redirects the basic click handler for the chip any special handling that happens on click may change and need to be repeated (e.g., ripple effect, but I don't think `FilterChip` has any by default?).

But it's good for a personal project.

```
  val clickHandler: () -> Unit = {
    // what you usually do on simple clicking the chip
  }
  FilterChip(
    label = {
      Text(
        species.common,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        fontWeight = if (focused) FontWeight.ExtraBold else FontWeight.Medium,
        modifier = Modifier
          .combinedClickable(
            onLongClick = {
              // what you want to do on long press
            },
            // necessary because you can't set a long click handler on Text
            // without handling clicks as well
            onClick = clickHandler, 
          ),
        onClick = clickHandler,
      )
    },
```